# Split flat file and add delimiter in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, split, delimiter

I would like how to improve a code that I have.

My shell script reads a flat file, and split it in two files based on first char of each line, header and detail. For header the first char is 1 and for detail is 2. Splitted files does not include the firts char.

Header is delimited by "|", and detail is fixed-width, so, I add the delimiter to it alter.

What I want is to do this in one single awk, to avoid creating a tmp file.

For splitting file I use and awk command, and for adding delimiter another awk command.

This is what I have now:

```
Input=Input.txt
Header=Header.txt
DetailTmp=DetailTmp.txt
Detail=Detail.txt

#First I split in two files and remove first char
awk -v vFileHeader="$Header" -v vFileDetail="$DetailTmp" '/^1/ {f=vFileHeader} /^2/ {f=vFileDetail} {sub(/^./,""); print > f}' $Input

#Then, I add the delimiter to detail
awk '{OFS="|"};{print substr($1,1,10),substr($1,11,5),substr($1,16,2),substr($1,18,14),substr($1,32,4),substr($1,36,18),substr($1,54,1)}' $DetailTmp > $Detail
```

Any suggestion?

Input.txt file

```
120190301|0170117174|FRANK|DURAND|USA
2017011717400052082911070900000000000000000000091430200
120190301|0170117204|ERICK|SMITH|USA
2017011720400052082911070900000000000000000000056311910
```

Header.txt splitted

```
20190301|0170117174|FRANK|DURAND|USA
20190301|0170117204|ERICK|SMITH|USA
```

DetailTmp.txt splitted

```
017011717400052082911070900000000000000000000091430200
017011720400052082911070900000000000000000000056311910
017011727100052052911070900000000000000000000008250000
017011718200052082911070900000000000000000000008102500
017011726300052052911070900000000000000000000008250000
```

**Detail.txt desired**

```
0170117174|00052|08|29110709000000|0000|000000000009143020|0
0170117204|00052|08|29110709000000|0000|000000000005631191|0
0170117271|00052|05|29110709000000|0000|000000000000825000|0
0170117182|00052|08|29110709000000|0000|000000000000810250|0
0170117263|00052|05|29110709000000|0000|000000000000825000|0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just combine the scripts

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' '/^1/{print substr($0,2) > "header"} 
                  /^2/{print substr($0,2,10),substr($0,11,5),... > "detail"}' file
```

however, you may be better off, using `FIELDWIDTHS` on the detail file on the second pass.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Can you explain and show an example of using FIELDWITHS ?